# How to concatenate two files with an indentifer in a loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have 200 files: `cool1.txt,cool2.txt,..., cool100.txt and warm1.txt, warm2.txt,...,warm100.txt.`

All files have 2 columns of data.

I would like to concatenate 200 files as follows to have `coolwarm1.txt ,coolwarm2.txt,coolwarm100.txt`

```
cat cool1.txt warm1.txt > coolwarm1.txt
cat cool2.txt warm2.txt > coolwarm2.txt
...
cat cool100.txt warm100.txt > coolwarm100.txt
```

Within each file of coolwarm*.txt, I like to add an identifier "cool" and "warm" after concatenating.

So for example, coolwarm1.txt would look like this

```
Input 
    cool1.txt 

    S44298 33307
    S46800 32286
    S55145 29361

    warm1.txt
    S10253 27473
    S24395 33093

Desired output for coolwarm1.txt

S44298 33307 cool
S46800 32286 cool
S55145 29361 cool
S10253 27473 warm
S24395 33093 warm
```

`awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' cool1.txt warm1.txt > coolwarm1.txt` would give 
     close to what I want, but I could not manage further.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for n in `seq 1 100`; do cat cool$n.txt | awk '{print $0 " cool"}' > coolwarm$n.txt; cat warm$n.txt | awk '{print $0 " warm"}' >> coolwarm$n.txt; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in 1 2  ; do cat cool${i}.txt | awk ' { print $1,$2,"cool" } ; ' ; cat warm${i}.txt | awk ' { print $1,$2,"warm" } ' ; done
S44298 33307 cool
S46800 32286 cool
S55145 29361 cool
S10253 27473 warm
S24395 33093 warm
S44298 33307 cool
S46800 32286 cool
S55145 29361 cool
S10253 27473 warm
S24395 33093 warm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for n in `seq 1..100`
do
sed 's/(.*)/\1 cool/' cool$n.txt >coolwarm$n.txt
sed 's/(.*)/\1 warm/' warm$n.txt >>coolwarm$n.txt
done
```

Comment: Interesting. Never thought of using sed in this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..100}
do
  awk '{print $0,FILENAME}' "cool${i}.txt" "warm${i}.txt" > "coolwarm${i}.txt"
done
```

if you just want "cool" and "warm" as identifier, do a `substring` on `FILENAME` as desired
eg `substr(FILENAME,1,4)`

Or you can be adventurous and do it in one `awk` script

```
#!/bin/bash

awk  'BEGIN{
    for( i=1 ; i <=100 ; i++ ){
       coolname= "cool"i".txt"
       warmname= "warm"i".txt"
       output = "coolwarm"i".txt"
       while( ( getline line < coolname ) >0 ) {
          print line" cool" >>  output
       }
       close( coolname )
       while ( ( getline line < warmname ) > 0  )  {
            print line" warm" >>  output
       }
       close( warmname )
    }
}'
```